# Symfony ManyToMany delete record

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I was trying to update a many to many relation between "book * <- -> * tag". For that, I first wanted to delete all current related tags of a book - to add afterwards again the changed /entered tags.
Deleting all tags of a book is working, but when a tag has no more books mapped, it does not get deleted:

```
 // remove all tags from book
    foreach($book->getTags() as $tag)
    {
        $tag->removeBook($book);

        // remove tag if no books are mapped anymore
        if(count($tag->getBooks()) == 0) {
            $this->em->remove($tag);
        }
        $this->em->persist($tag);
    }
    $this->em->flush();
```

Why does it not delete the $tag (A tag entity object) if the count returns 0 (I already checked that it enteres the block.

The Owning Side of my relation is the "Tag"-Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply removing `Tag` if `count($tag->getBooks()) == 0`:

```
$this->em->remove($tag);
```

and persisting it again:

```
$this->em->persist($tag);
```

`else` is required:

```
if(count($tag->getBooks()) == 0) {
    $this->em->remove($tag);
} else {
    $this->em->persist($tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clarifying your mixture:

> remove an entity:

```
$this->em->remove($tag);
```

> add / change an entity:

```
$this->em->persist($tag);
```

> In both cases, you will need at the end:

```
$this->em->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try putting the persist operation in an `else` statement.

Although I haven't tested it, it seems to me that in this case, whether you delete a tag or not, you always end up persisting the tag again.